# How to combine two multidimensional arrays in php where one key's value is same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array i want to combine it but condition's are if **Val** is similar and **code** are the exact match then combine otherwise push as it is.

> Array

```
$Array1 = array(array("id" => 1,"val" => 'Hotel royal', "code" => '110088', ),array("id" => 2,"val" => 'Hotel Club Town', "code" => '110084', ),array("id" => 4,"val" => "Hotel Park Club ", "code" => '110088',));
$Array2 = array(array("id" => 2,"val" => 'Hotel royal delhi', "code" => '110088',),array("id" => 1,"val" => "Hotel Club's Town", "code" => '110084',),array("id" => 6,"val" => "Hotel Park Club's Delhi ", "code" => '110088',));
```

> Want OutPut

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [val] => Hotel royal
                    [code] => 110088
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [val] => Hotel Royal Delhi
                    [code] => 110088
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [val] => Hotel Club Town
                    [code] => 110084
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [val] => Hotel Club's Town
                    [code] => 110084
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [val] => Hotel Park Club 
                    [code] => 110088
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [val] => Hotel Park Club's Delhi 
                    [code] => 110088
                )
        )
)
```

> I have tried this code

```
foreach ($Array1 as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($Array2 as $value2) {
        if ($value['id'] == $value2['id']) {
            $array_new[$key] = array($value,$value2);
        }
        elseif (!$value['id'] == $value2['id']) {
            $array_new[$key] = array($value,$value2);
        }
    }
}
```

but this code is not returning desire output.

Comment: `if Val is similar` ...this is an Unclear requirement.  What is "similar" to one person will differ from what another person considers "similar".  This question doesn't have a clear problem statement.  I have voted to close as Unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Both array require the same proccesing, so you can merge them in one loop

```
$res = array();
foreach (array_merge($Array1,$Array2)  as $value) 
    $res[$value['id']][] =  $value;

print_r($res);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/583331)

If you want regular array, just set after loop `$res = array_values($res);`

Comment: Hi @splash58 i have edited the question i am trying to figure out this but i am not be able to do. so can you please help me in this.

Comment: i dont undestant the logic of array building

Comment: There are two array conditions are 
Array1 - **"val"** is similar to Array2 - **"val"** `&&`
Array1 - **"code"** is the exact match of Array2 - **"code"** then combine
otherwise push as it is.

For Example:

Array1 - **"val" => 'Hotel royal'** is similar to Array2 - **"val" => 'Hotel royal delhi'** And 
Array1 - **"code" => '110088'** is the exact match of Array2 - **"code" => '110088'**

Comment: i still don't understand what you want. Perhaps, it's better to create new question in hope that someone could help you